# React hooks window.scrollTo(0, 0) not working when overflow auto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, dom-events, scrollto

I am using React at the moment, when I click on a button that takes me to another page, by default it goes to the bottom of my page. Tried using window.scrollTo(0, 0); but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const handleRedirection = () => {
    history.push(/home);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
```

The page I would like to go to currently has css set as

```
height: calc(100vh - 50px);
overflow: scroll;
```

Was wondering is there a solution to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: `history.push(/home);` <-- This is not valid JS.

Comment: Take a look here: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration. It looks like the <ScrollToTop> component is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll to top based on route change

try this:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

//your codes code

  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

//your codes
```

also, you can use it as a top-level component to apply this to all your pages